# Bilinear form for general linear group

Tags: group-theory, bilinear-form

I have the statement [image]

in the book " 3-d transposition groups" by Michael Aschbacher. What does this mean?

Does this mean that the general linear group can be regarded as the isometry group of a null vector space?

I am struggling to find anything that mentions a bilinear form for the general linear group.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

given a vector space with a fixed basis, a quadratic form is given by $v^T H v,$ where $H$ is symmetric  and $v$ a column vector and $v^T H v$ a 1 by 1 matrix, i.e. a number.
next, an isometry is a nonsingular linear transformation, take it as an invertible matrix $P$, such that
$$  P^T HP = H.  $$

Finally, if $H$ is the zero matrix, then $P$ can be any invertible matrix, as $P^T 0 P = 0$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. Does H not have to be invertible too for this to describe the general linear group?